# How to insert text at caret position in SynEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

There is a procedure SynEdit.InsertTextAtCaret('Text') for Lazarus version of SynEdit. How to insert text at caret for Delphi version of SynEdit with undo support?

Comment: Assigning value to the `SelText` property might work (I just quickly looked in the source).

Comment: Thank you Victoria. I am certainly going to use that for selected text to be replaced with my custom text but, I also want to be able to insert text when SelText is nil i.e. just at the blinking caret position without any selection existing.

Comment: Well, usual edit control concept of selection is that there's always a starting selection index, and selection length is 0 when there is no selection which actually stands for caret position. Hence I was hoping it might work. Well, then you can follow what's inside `PasteFromClipboard` method, just instead of working with clipboard use the text you're about to insert and slightly modify the logged undo actions.

Comment: That indeed is an alternative solution you can post as answer Victoria. I thought of using it as the last measure since clipboard change will trigger other parts of my special application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is procedure

```
TCustomSynEdit.procedure InsertBlock(const BB, BE: TBufferCoord; ChangeStr: PWideChar; AddToUndoList: Boolean);
```

It inserts ChangeStr changing text from BB to BE position.
You may set BB and BE to current caret coordinates and you'll get what you want

For example

```
SynEdit1.InsertBlock(SynEdit1.CaretXY, SynEdit1.CaretXY, 'test', true);
```

Comment: While the answer is perfect right, and even supports undo, that `InsertBlock` method seems to have some bugs with undo/redo. SynEdit does not restore the old caret position after `InsertBlock()`, and paints whitespaces where none is.

Comment: Which version is this? I use Delphi 11 and SynEdit from Embarcadero ( https://getitnow.embarcadero.com/SynEdit-2021.08cb-Sydney ), this InsertBlock method is not available.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
SynEdit1.InsertTextAtCaret('text');
```

Comment: Not available in Delphi, it is in Lazarus edition only